# Visual Studio 2010 IDE - unpinning Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

Is there a way to have the Toolbox automatically pinned when I am in design mode and un-pinned when I am in code view?...or even further, can I pin/un-pin certain windows based on when I switch between design/code view?

Answer (score 1):

Not as a standard option, I'm afraid. You can possibly write your own plugin to do this job but the time it takes may be a false economy!